# ¿Como puedo insertar datos de un dataframe en otro si cumple una condición?

Tags: python

Muy buenas, tengo dos dataframe que adjunto aquí abajo, y estoy tratando de hacer que si la fecha de Boro es igual a la fecha de Datoscomparativos copie en Boro la celda de CaptureSite de datoscomparativos, y si no está nos existe devuelva n/a

Para ello he probado sin exito:

```
if Boro.Date_TimeCaught = datoscomparativos.Date_TimeCaught:
    insert datoscomparativos.CaptureSite on boro.CaptureSite
```

y

```
def main():
    if Boro.Date_TimeCaught is datoscomparativos.Date_TimeCaught:
        datoscomparativos.CaptureSite in Boro.CaptureSite
        else: n/a
```

Aquí os adjunto una muestra de referencia de ambas bbdd.

Muchas gracias por su atención

[image: Imagen ref]

Comment: ¿Puedes pegar como texto un ejemplo de ambos dataframes? (vale delimitado por comas como en un csv). O mejor aún, un enlace de dónde descargar esos .csv, para poder hacer pruebas con ellos y elaborar una respuesta.

Comment: En el primer caso que probaste sin exito debería de mandarte un error de sintaxis, ya que estás usando asignación (=) en lugar de comparación (==)